# Is there any reason to share a dispatch queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working on some code that I can't contact the original developer.

He passes a class a reference to another class's serial dispatch queue and I'm not seeing any purpose to him not just creating another dispatch queue (each class is a singleton).

It's not creating issues but I'd like to understand it further, so any insight into the positive implications is appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I suggest reading all the answers here, they explain a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually not a good idea to share queues in this fashion (and no, not because they are expensive - they're not, quite the converse).  The rationale is that it's not clear to anyone but a queue's creator just what the semantics of the queue are.  Is it serial?  Concurrent?  High priority?  Low priority?  All are possible, and once you start passing internal queues around which were actually created for the benefit of a specific class, the external caller can schedule work on it which causes a mutual deadlock or otherwise behaves in an unexpected fashion with the other items on that queue because caller A knew to expect concurrent behavior and caller B was thinking it was a serial queue, without any of the "gotchas" that concurrent execution implies.

Queues should therefore, wherever possible, be hidden implementation details of a class.  The class can export methods for scheduling work against its internal queue as necessary, but the methods should be the only accessors since they are the only ones who know for sure how to best access and schedule work on that specific type of queue!

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the well written response.  There are a lot of helpful answers here but for the sake of promoting best practices I'm marking yours as correct.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a serial queue, then they may be intending to serialize access to some resource shared between all objects that share it.

Comment: Thank you, and yes it is a serial queue (I've edited question to reflect that)

Comment: This is the most common reason for the sharing of a serial queue that I've seen in my travels.

Comment: And if its not a serial queue? IMHO, if there is a need to expose a queue, it should be done by the call-site for executing completion handlers or progress handlers. An associated asynchronous task's work load SHOULD be executed on their own private queue. IMO, the OPs description is a potential code smell.

Comment: I suppose a shared concurrent queue could be used for its suspension semantics but that would be quite unusual. I agree it's likely not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch queues are somewhat expensive to create, and tie up system resources. If you can share one, the system runs more efficiently. For that matter, if your app does work in the background, using a shared queue allows you to manage a single pool of tasks to be completed. So yes, there are good reasons for using a shared dispatch queue.

Comment: My knowledge of GCD is spotty (which I'm reading up on as fast as possible to correct) but why does having a single queue run better than having two?

Comment: I disagree that queues are "expensive" to create and "tie up [meaningful amounts of] system resources". There's not a 1:1 relationship between dispatch queues and kernel mutexes or anything like that. Empirically, I observe that allocating a `dispatch_queue_t` costs 128 bytes of heap, and that you can allocate 10 million of them in a few seconds.